# How to open an android application from browser

Tags: android, android-intent, schema

The schema given is "desk://" to my application.How can i open my application when I call this from my browser?I went through many sites but could not properly come to a conclusion.

Comment: *I went through many sites but could not properly come to a conclusion.*  so at least write **what had you tried** to avoid giving you the same solution

Comment: If my answer was helpful you may want to mark that as the solution so your problem may be shown as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what your asking with my personal website by adding the following elements to my Activity's Intent Filter in my Manifest:

```
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="zackmatthews.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/projects/"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="www.zackmatthews.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/projects/"
                android:scheme="http" />
```

This produced the following output when clicking a link to my projects page: 
[image: Open with dialog]